# Django registration with groups: Group matching query does not exist

Tags: django, registration

I'm trying to allocate groups permissions in my register form, but I get this error:

Group matching query does not exist.

forms.py:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    Group = [('Viewers', 'Viewers'), ('Editors', 'Editors'), ('Creators', 'Creators'), ]
    group_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Group)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'group_name', )
```

views.py:

```
def registerView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='group_name')
            user.groups.add(group)
            return redirect('accounts:users')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

The error occurs at group = Group.objects.get(name='group_name').
No idea how to fix it

Comment: Like the error says, there is simply no group with the `name` `'group_name'``.

Comment: You don't have any groups named 'group_name'. You need to use a variable instead of a string literal or set it to valid name as defined in your Group tuple in RegisterForm.

Comment: Your `User` has likely no field `group_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
group = Group.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('group_name'))

or form.cleaned_data['group_name']
```

as you are taking a input from the form you need to access the field from the form to get the value of that input name.